# Rendering a template in Symfony2 Console application

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-console

I am using Symfony 2.8 and I want to render a template in a Symfony Console application. Basically I can render the template but it is trying to fetch assets from `file` protocol. I need those assets to be fetched from `http` protocol in order to creating a pdf from that template. I did try [scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) but it did not work.

Actually the question is that I want the template to be rendered with correct asset and image urls. I want to get fully rendered html.